# Proper way of standardizing images

Tags: php, amazon-product-advertising-api

I am building a web application that will use the Amazon Product Advertising API. The problem is that the API returns images of different sizes and aspect ratios for each product. If I resize all images to a static width/height, then some of them look odd due to the change in ratio. The images will be laid out in rows of four each. I was thinking that I will only make the width of the images the same while keeping the aspect ratio the same and then having some sort of max threshold for the height just in case the API returns some oddly sized image.

But, I wanted to see if people here have ran into this before and what their thoughts on this design problem are?

Comment: I think what you propose is a sane way of going about the task, you already highlighted the most important issue and that is keeping the ratio correct.

Comment: @Fluitketel I don't own the images. The Amazon API dynamically returns an image url based upon a search. I am performing multiple searches and getting a separate image url for each search and each of those images has a different size and ratio. Each page can contain as many as 12 images and it takes long enough to perform the searches that truly resizing the bitmap would not be feasible.

Comment: @sabre Yep, I tried to ignore the problem and just resize everything to a static width-x and width-y but eventually it bothered me enough to ask here. I am debating switching to a carousel versus rows of images to de-emphasize the size mismatch.

Comment: I think this is a matter of opinion. Do you stretch the images?  Do you crop them?  Do you letterbox them?  All of those solutions have drawbacks.  Different situations are going to call for different solutions based on what you are willing to compromise on.

Answer (score 2):

What a co-incidence. I was facing a similar problem and this is how I've decided to move forward. It might not be the best solution, but it works for me.

First I get the original height and width of the image

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize("path to image");
```

Then I find out the greatest common divisor for the two and store the width and height ratios in variables, such as `$wr` and `$hr`

Then check for image orientation is made (horizontal or vertical) by comparing `$wr > $hr` for horizontal orientation and `$hr > $wr` for vertical

If horizontal, I make sure the thumb size does not exceed a certain value, say 120px and make the height corresponding to 120px based on aspect ratio. The same is done if the orientation is vertical.

Comment: ah awesome. I did not even think to check for horizontal vs vertical. I will try it out real quick and see at least subjectively, which looks better.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem trying to standardize logos. At first, I thought that I could choose a standard area and resize all the images to that area, but there are two problems with that strategy. First, you have to set limits for height and width, so sometimes you end up images with a smaller area because they are very wide or tall. Secondly, that might make your layout look ugly. In my case I have a header on top, an image and then text below. I realized that a very wide image would leave a big gap between the header and the text. Because of that, I needed a solution that would give preference to width. What I mean by that is that the image can change a lot in width without changing the height a lot. Different applications may have different requirements, but I think my solution allows for any situation such as a preference for height as well:

```
function width_to_height($width, $slope, $icpt){
    if ($width == 0){
        return FALSE;
    }
    return floor(($icpt + sqrt(pow($icpt, 2) + 4*$slope*pow($width, 2)))/(2*$width));
} 

function ratio_to_height($ratio, $slope, $icpt){
    if ($ratio == 0){
        return FALSE;
    }
    $area = $ratio*$slope + $icpt;
    return floor(sqrt($area/$ratio));
}   

function calc_dims($width, $height, $max_w=168, $max_h=100){
    $slope = 2500;
    $icpt = 6000;
    $ratio = $width/$height;
    $max_ratio = $max_w/$this->width_to_height($max_w, $slope, $icpt);
    if ($ratio > $max_ratio){
        $ht = floor($max_w/$ratio);
        return array('width' => $max_w, 'height' => $ht);
    }
    $ht = $this->ratio_to_height($ratio, $slope, $icpt);
    if ($ht > $max_h){
        $wd = floor($max_h*$ratio);
        return array('width' => $wd, 'height' => $max_h);
    }
    $wd = floor($ht*$ratio);
    return array('width' => $wd, 'height' => $ht);
}
```

The main function is calc_dims() which calls the other two functions. Since I almost always work with classes, these functions are called with the "this->" operator. If you don't use classes, you can simply delete the operator.

You can see that I hard-coded some variables. (In my real life application, these are called from a configuration file.) $max_w and $max_h are pretty self explanatory as the maximum height and width of the images. However $slope and $icpt may be a little more difficult to understand. As you can see in the ratio_to_height() function, $slope and $icpt (intercept) are components in a linear relationship between area and the aspect ratio of the image.

You can use the values that I provide ($slope = 2500; $icpt = 6000), or you can calculate your own. I thought of automating the process a little more, but since the parameters are highly subjective, it didn't seem very practical. In order to calculate them, it's necessary to define areas for two different instances of the aspect ratios, where the ratio is $width/$height. For example, when the ratio is 1 ($width = $height), you might want the area to be 8000 pixels^2, and when the ratio is 2 ($width = 2*$height) the area could be 12000 pixels^2. With these values we have:

```
$A1 = 8000;
$A2 = 12000;
$r1 = 1;
$r2 = 2;
```

You can calculate slope and intercept as follows:

```
$slope = ($A2 - $A1)/($r2 - $r1);
$icpt = $A1 - $slope*$r1;
```